# IOS - How to update the view in presentModalViewController?

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am new to IOS development.
In my app I want to replace the view model that's being presented.
I show my initial view by calling: presentModalViewController

When I replace the view, I don't want the entire animation to run.
I just simply want to change the presentModalViewController underlaying view to update.

When I set:

```
self.presentModalViewController.view = myCustomViewController.view
```

it works great for the first time, and really does replace the view
But when I try doing it again and replace the view's content at some other point in my application's live, the presentModalViewController does not update.

How can I update the view in presentModalViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends of what you are trying to achieve.

1 - Does the new view has an entirely new behavior? Perhaps using a new `UIViewController` might be a solution.

2 - If you answer **no** to the first, then a secondary `UIView` inside the XIB will do the trick. As long as you have access to it with an `IBOUtlet`.

---

**Edit 1:**

> I show my initial view by calling: presentModalViewController

If you are showing it (that's where you are), your course of action should be inside of it, and not outside. For instance:

```
self.view = mySecondaryView;
```

Comment: I see, well It is a completely new course of action. thing is that if I call presentModalViewController again, this time on my new UIViewController i get a delayed view loaded. I want it to just 'replace' or update the current view

Comment: Again, if you don't need a special behavior, just add the `UIView` you want to be used inside your XIB. Then it's a simple.